# HTML input > file "video/*" > iPhone X codec issue

Tags: ios, video-capture, video-encoding, iphone-x, html-input

I noticed that **iPhone X** give different "codeced" video files to a input like this

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*">
```

depending if it directly captures the video from the cam => **MPEG-H Part2/HEVC (H.265)**

or select a video from the phone => **H265 - MPEG-4 AVC**

---

I was able to test this with a **iPhone 7** on iOS 11. Both ways => **H265 - MPEG-4 AVC**

---

Both iPhones have enabled the "High Efficiency" camera setting

All tests with **Safari**

I did the codec checks with VLC

---

Can anyone confirm this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: +1 I can also confirm this suboptimal to horrible behaviour with an iPhoneX! I already opened a similar issue inside the react-dropzone-component github: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component/issues/175

Comment: I have a problem with dealing with h265 also and I am also suprised that there is not much about how to deal with this video format. Any news?

Comment: More details to the support of this format: https://caniuse.com/#feat=hevc